# Sybase to MSSQL migration: Lock Datarows while create table

Tags: sql-server, locking, database-migration, sybase, dbmigrate

I am migrating a **Sybase** DB to a **SQL Server** DB. I can see that existing Sybase tables have `lock datarows` or `lock allpages` specified along with `create table` statement something like this:

```
create table new_publishers 
(
    pub_id     char(4)      not null,
    pub_name   varchar(40)  null,
    city       varchar(20)  null,
    state      char(2)      null
)
lock datarows
```

However, I could not find a way to do the same thing in SQL Server.

Can someone please tell me how to do this in SQL Server?

Comment: i think you can use the default which is allow page and allow row locking

Comment: @siggemannen Sorry can you please elaborate a bit? How to use that?

Comment: You don't need to do anything is what @siggemannen  is saying as, by default, both [`ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#allow_row_locks---on--off-) and [`ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#allow_page_locks---on--off-) are set to `ON`. Are you, perhaps, wanting to disallow Page locks? *Why*? (Because we do in SyBase isn't an answer.)

Comment: @ThomA Aah understood. No, I do not want to disable it. I just wanted to replicate whatever is there in the legacy application so that once I start migrating the code base that will use this DB, I face limited to no issues. I believe ```lock datarows``` will lock only data row which is being modified by application because it is specified explicitly. Could you please tell me how will MSSQL decide which lock scheme to use?

Comment: Why, and when, SQL Server chooses to use a row/page lock would be better asked about on [dba.se], @CyberMafia .

Comment: @ThomA I think what's being asked is how to modify the current `create table` script so that it works in SQL Server and provides the same benefit; is the answer a simple `remove the 'lock datarows' clause`? or someting more involved like `replace the 'lock datarows' clause with 'some_SQL_Server_specific' clause`?

Comment: @ThomA I just want to know if there is any way to achieve the same thing as sybase create table along with lock datarows scheme in SQL Server? So it is like enforcing datarows lock scheme during table creation itself.  Or the only option is to specify lock scheme along with every query in application?

Comment: So, in  your opinion, what does `lock datarows` do when you add it to the `CREATE TABLE` statement? How does it differ from, say, omitting the clause entirely?

Comment: @ThomA Apologies for the late reply. I think adding ```lock datarows``` with ```CREATE TABLE``` will make sure that whenever an application is trying to run select query then only the matching rows are locked. 

Omitting it would not really guarantee that is what I believe.